# Hot deployment not working

Tags: tomcat, liferay, liferay-6

I am using Liferay Portal 6.1 CE.

I have setup the developement environment  in eclipse indigo.

When i deploy a portlet ,it moves to the deploy folder inside the Portal Bundle.But didn't  get deployed.
I have already tested with the other War,placed in deploy folder.but same happens

Hot deployment is not working. 
What i can do?Help me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be that you moved an installation and your current settings include a liferay.home that is different from what you expect.

At startup of Liferay, the log states what auto-deploy directory Liferay monitors. Look for a line in tomcat/logs/catalina.out that looks like this:

```
08:34:58,902 INFO  [pool-2-thread-1][ServerDetector:154] Server supports hot deploy
08:34:58,910 INFO  [pool-2-thread-1][PluginPackageUtil:1030] Reading plugin package for the root context
08:35:01,137 INFO  [pool-2-thread-1][AutoDeployDir:106] Auto deploy scanner started for /opt/lds/lds161/liferay-portal-6.1.20-ee-ga2/deploy
```

Also, whatever user Tomcat/Liferay runs as, needs to have read/write access to this directory as well as to tomcat's webapps directory in order for hot-deploy to work. Plugins will not be deployed if they can't be removed from the auto-deploy folder.

Commonly, you'll find a liferay.home setting in portal-setup-wizard.properties (this is the default parent directory of the deploy directory), but this setting might also have been transitioned into your database (in case you're wondering why changes to this value won't be picked up.

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 questions I could see in your post.

`1.` *Hot deployment is not working*

Make sure you have specified the hot deployment folder in `portal-ext.properties` file.

`auto.deploy.deploy.dir=/app/portal/liferay-portal-6/deploy`

You can then deploy your war files in /app/portal/liferay-portal-6/deploy folder.

Liferay picks that up and puts that in /app/portal/liferay-portal-6/../server/default/deploy folder.

More details could be found [here](http://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/user-guide/-/ai/auto-deploy).

`2.`  *it moves to the deploy folder inside the Portal Bundle.But didn't get deployed*

Do you see any exceptions in your logs? Doesn't it say 1 Portlet available for use?

Comment: as per http://www.liferay.com/community/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Hot+Deploy+Troubleshooting , property name should be  auto.deploy.dest.dir

Answer (score 1):

check auto deploy path in server config.[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to add following entries in build.(user_name).properties in your plugin sdk. If you didn't find this file, you need to create it. set you directories like

> app.server.parent.dir=D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1
>
> app.server.portal.dir = D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps\ROOT
>
> app.server.lib.global.dir = D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\lib\ext
>
> app.server.deploy.dir = D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42\webapps
>
> app.server.type = tomcat
>
> app.server.dir = D:\Projects\Site\liferay-portal-6.2.0-ce-ga1\tomcat-7.0.42

Hope this will help you.